# CreateSimpleReBar in WTL vista/7 native look and feel

Tags: c++, menubar, wtl

When using the CreateSimpleReBar in WTL the main menu bar has this blue color on mouse hover and not the native vista/7 round and transparent shape. Also for some reason the menu bar seems taller then the usual native one.

Does CreateSimpleReBar draw the menu itself or am I missing something?

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/259/wtlmainmenu.png/

```
HWND hWndCmdBar = m_CmdBar.Create(m_hWnd, rcDefault, NULL, ATL_SIMPLE_CMDBAR_PANE_STYLE);
// attach menu
m_CmdBar.AttachMenu(GetMenu());

// load command bar images
m_CmdBar.LoadImages(IDR_MAINFRAME);
// remove old menu
SetMenu(NULL);

// Set m_hWndToolBar member
CreateSimpleReBar(ATL_SIMPLE_REBAR_NOBORDER_STYLE);

// Add a band to the rebar represented by m_hWndToolBar
AddSimpleReBarBand(hWndCmdBar);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateSimpleReBar` creates a rebar control, and the menu is one of the rebar bands, created by `m_CmdBar.Create` - WTL's `CCommandBarCtrl` class. The latter custom-draws the menu to mimic OS behavior, including blue highlighting with `COLOR_MENUHILIGHT` (atlctrlw.h).

Comment: So CCommandBarCtrl is using owner-draw to draw the menu. Not a very good way to be adaptable with new Windows versions, imo. Perhaps one could use SetMenuItemBitmaps()?

Comment: You have choices. Standard menu (old school) including custom-drawn, command bar is still not that bad, fancy ribbon.

Comment: I got my hands dirty in the win32 api and got it working using SetMenuItemInfo(). http://pastebin.com/Ba2TCH7Q